# Ubuntu MATE won't boot: "Kernel panic - not syncing" and "error while loading shared libraries"

Tags: kernel, ubuntu-mate, shared-library, init

Nothing was done to prompt this error, simply booting my computer and it gave me an error (which I cannot remember) which was (presumably) fixed by entering

fsck -fy /dev/sda2

I then rebooted my computer and am now presented with this error:

"end Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exercise=0x00007f00"

"/sbin/init: error while loading shared libraries: libip4tc.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

(Cannot post image due to low reputation)

This happens when booted both normally and under recovery mode, it is also frozen and I cannot input anything

Is there anyway I can fix this without losing my data? (Installed programs such as PyCharm and Steam)

EDIT: I am using version 4.15.0-43-generic of Ubuntu MATE

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ah yes sorry I forgot to include this because it was originally in the photo before I learned I could not post a picture. I am using version 4.15

Comment: Xenial or Bionic - 16.04 LTS or 18.04 LTS?

Comment: Sorry I edited my previous comment I'm on Ubuntu MATE 4.15.0-43-generic

Answer (score 0):

Your Linux kernel version indicate that you are using Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

In this Ubuntu version mentioned library is contained in [`libip4tc0` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libip4tc.so.0).

You should do the following:

1. Boot from installation medium
2. Mount your problematic Ubuntu root filesystem with Caja by clicking on the drive icon in the *Devices* section

   [image: mount in Caja]

   If unsure which partition to mount then check it with Disks (`gnome-disks`) utility and mount it from here:

   [image: mount from Disks]
3. Then download [deb-file](http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iptables/libip4tc0_1.6.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb) and extract it to the root file-system

   ```
   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/i/iptables/libip4tc0_1.6.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -x libip4tc0_1.6.1-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb /media/ubuntu-mate/ba94799c-*

   wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/lz4/liblz4-1_0.0~r131-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -x liblz4-1_0.0~r131-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb /media/ubuntu-mate/ba94799c-*
   ```
4. Check that above operation do not have errors and then reboot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87814/discussion-between-retsek-and-n0rbert).